# Angular - can't sum point

Tags: angular8

I want to sum point but now I try write function and console.log(total) but it happens is 'undefined'

app.ts

```
  saveTasks() {
    if (this.tasksToSave.length != 0) {
      for (let i = 0; this.tasksToSave.length > i; i++) {
        this.ticketService.setAddTasks(
          this.id,
          this.tasksToSave[i]
        )
      }
     }
   }
  sumPoint() {
    let total = 0
    if (this.tasksToSave.length != 0) {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.tasksToSave.length; i++) {
        total = total + this.tasksToSave[i].point
      }
    }
  }
```

app.html

```
total = {{total}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `total` variable in the `export` block in the `component` like below:

```
    export class YourComponent implements OnInit {
      ...
      total: number = 0;
      ...    
      sumPoint() {        
          if (this.tasksToSave.length != 0) {
           for (let i = 0; i < this.tasksToSave.length; i++) {
            this.total = this.total + this.tasksToSave[i].point
           }
         }
       }          
      ...
    }
```